# Aligning the Image in the center of the screen

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I want to align the image in the center of the screen, while the hamburger and search are on the leftmost side of the navbar.

##### site-header.tsx

```html
<header className="sticky top-0 z-40 border-b bg-black bg-opacity-40">
  <div className="flex h-16 w-max items-center ">
    <MainNav />
  </div>
</header>
```

##### main-nav.tsx

```js
export function MainNav() {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="flex flex-wrap items-center justify-center">
        <div className="flex">
          <SideNav />
          <Search href="/" className="cursor-pointer" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="flex items-center justify-center align-middle">
        <Image
          src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a3/Fast_Company_logo.svg/120px-Fast_Company_logo.svg.png?20180515163340"
          alt="Logo"
          width={120}
          height={28}
        />
      </div>
    </>
  )
```

##### layout.tsx

```html
<ThemeProvider attribute="class" defaultTheme="system" enableSystem>
  <div className="relative flex min-h-screen flex-col ">
    <SiteHeader />
    <div className="flex-1">{children}</div>
  </div>
  <TailwindIndicator />
</ThemeProvider>
```

I have tried aligning `items-center`, `justify-content` and `flex` but it didn't work at all.

Comment: when you use those properties, it centers the image inside the container. If the container isn't the size of the screen, the image will consequently not be at the center of the screen.

Comment: Your intentions can be interpreted in different ways. Can you include images of the current and desired result?

Comment: Sure, https://imgur.com/a/bKuOTQM, this contains the current and desired result. Appreciate the help

Comment: Since we have [a live working example](https://www.fastcompany.com/90907243/what-are-aqi-and-pm2-5-explaining-air-pollution-measurements-that-are-spiking-from-wildfire-smoke) to examine, we can view the source and/or use Developer Tools to see that the Fast Company website is using absolute positioning to position the elements of their navbar